# Log the result on the console asp.net Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core

I want to make test for my application and for that I'm getting the informations from Prometheus API, I put that on a model and I try to get the data extracted from my controller. 
How can I get the data on my console ( something like `Console.Write`), do you have any ideas of how to do that ? I'v tried also debugging and I dont know how to work with visual studio debogger.
Please be gentle I'm a newbie, thank you.

my model of data where I will get the Json Data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using System.Globalization;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

namespace Prometheus_test_api.Models
{
    public partial class FreeDiskSpace
    {
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public string Status { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("data")]
        public Data Data { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Data
    {
        [JsonProperty("resultType")]
        public string ResultType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("result")]
        public Result[] Result { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Result
    {
        [JsonProperty("metric")]
        public Metric Metric { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("value")]
        public Value[] Value { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Metric
    {
        [JsonProperty("__name__")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("instance")]
        public string Instance { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("job")]
        public string Job { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("volume")]
        public string Volume { get; set; }
    }

    public partial struct Value
    {
        public double? Double;
        public string String;

        public static implicit operator Value(double Double) => new Value { Double = Double };
        public static implicit operator Value(string String) => new Value { String = String };
    }

    internal static class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
            Converters =
            {
                ValueConverter.Singleton,
                new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeStyles = DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal }
            },
        };
    }

    internal class ValueConverter : JsonConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvert(Type t) => t == typeof(Value) || t == typeof(Value?);

        public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type t, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            switch (reader.TokenType)
            {
                case JsonToken.Integer:
                case JsonToken.Float:
                    var doubleValue = serializer.Deserialize<double>(reader);
                    return new Value { Double = doubleValue };
                case JsonToken.String:
                case JsonToken.Date:
                    var stringValue = serializer.Deserialize<string>(reader);
                    return new Value { String = stringValue };
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot unmarshal type Value");
        }

        public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object untypedValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        {
            var value = (Value)untypedValue;
            if (value.Double != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.Double.Value);
                return;
            }
            if (value.String != null)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, value.String);
                return;
            }
            throw new Exception("Cannot marshal type Value");
        }

        public static readonly ValueConverter Singleton = new ValueConverter();
    }
}
```

and my controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Prometheus_test_api.Models;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug;

namespace Prometheus_test_api.Controllers
{
    public class FreeDiskSpaceController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<FreeDiskSpaceController> _logger;

        public FreeDiskSpaceController(ILogger<FreeDiskSpaceController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            IEnumerable<FreeDiskSpace> JsonData = null;

            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress 
                    = new Uri("http://localhost:9090/api/v1/query?");
                //HTTP GET
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("query=wmi_logical_disk_free_bytes");
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<IList<FreeDiskSpace>>();
                    readTask.Wait();

                    JsonData = readTask.Result;
                }
                else //web api sent error response 
                {
                    //log response status here..

                    JsonData = Enumerable.Empty<FreeDiskSpace>();

                    ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Server error. Please contact administrator.");
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine(JsonData);
            return View(JsonData);
        }
    }
}
```

if its possible help me log my informations on a Razor page or in the console, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put a debbug stop on any line by pressing F9 and drag your mouse over the variable that you want to inspect, the VS will show what it's stored inside that variable.

OBS: Be sure to run your project in DEBUG mode, if it's in Release, VS will ignore your stops

Comment: I have tried to , I dont know where to see what's stored inside the variable

Comment: Use watch tab within visual studio to see what are the values assigned or you could hover around the variable to see the assignment during debugging.

Answer (score 0):

You can do Console.WriteLine(). The result will be in the terminal. When the Index action method is invoked the "this will log in the console" will appear in the terminal.

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    Console.WriteLine("this will log in the console");
    //controller code will be here
    return View(JsonData);
}
```